# can someone give me a hand and example this script? django

Tags: python, django, authentication, model

I found a script online which helps me changing login to use both username and email instead of just username, but there are quite a lot of parts which I don't really understand.

Like, I understand pretty much what each line means but I don't get why by doing that would make my login work with email.

```
class EmailBackend(object):
    def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None):
        user_cls = get_user_model()
        try:
            user = user_cls.objects.get(email=username)
            if user.check_password(password):
                return user
        except user_cls.DoesNotExist:
            return None
        except:
            return None

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        user_cls = get_user_model()
        try:
            return user_cls.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except user_cls.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this script use username title instead of email but in backend this username must be an email `user = user_cls.objects.get(email=username)` you can change username to email, doesnt matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check comments :-

```
class EmailBackend(object):
    def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None):
        user_cls = get_user_model() #Getting user object in one variable

        try:
            user = user_cls.objects.get(email=username) #Check any user exist with input email(username) with database email(consider as an username)
            if user.check_password(password): #if user match then check is password match or not 
                return user #If both email and password match then return user information
        except user_cls.DoesNotExist: #if user not exist then return None
            return None
        except: #got any error in middle return None
            return None

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        user_cls = get_user_model() #Get user object in one variable
        try:
            return user_cls.objects.get(pk=user_id) #check user with this user_id exist or not, may be PK (some unique id consider as an user_id)
        except user_cls.DoesNotExist: #if user_id(PK) not exist return None 
            return None
```

Comment: but how does the username in `(email=username)` got here though? is it because of the `def authenticate` that it's actually a built-in in django? and how is `def get_user` being used? Without this in my `html` template there would be an error.

Comment: @Tsuna, may be in model it is email and they have consider username as an email so, they are comparing username with email. `get_user` is a function which they have create to check particular user data(pk) is available in database or not. Without this your template may not be working because may be they have called this function over their in template with parameter as user_id.